# Same Fact Table Column; Records with Multiple Reasons

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I am in a situation similar to the one below:

Think for instance we need to store customer sales in a fact table (under a data warehouse built with dimensional modelling). I have sales, discounts related to the sale, sales returns and cancellations to be stored.

Do you think it would be advisable to store sales for a day to a customer in a particular product (when the day is the grain) as a positive value while the returns and discounts are stored as minuses?

Also if a discount is enforced to a customer at a level other than the product (for instance brand), do you think it is alright to persist it with a key particularly assigned to the brand (product is the grain) while the product column being given an N/A, for the particular record?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sales are considered a good thing (I'm assuming they are) then recording sales as positive numbers makes perfect sense.  Any transaction that reduces sales (i.e. discounts and returns) should therefore be recorded as negative numbers.  This will make reporting your sales very natural.

If you have diffent dimensions that might account for a record, you should populate the dimensions that make sense.  So yes, attribute a discount to a brand rather than a product if that is what happened in your business transaction.  This way your reporting will be able to look at all discounts, at discounts for particular products and discounts for entire brands.  If your fact table shows the most direct "cause" of the discount (product or brand) then your reports will be more useful than if you link the fact to brand through a relationship to product.

Comment: Hi @Joel, thank you very much. Actually I have the product its brand etc. in the same dimension table. What I planned was to give the brand a separate key in the same table itself and use it in the fact table (as we use smart keys with regard to persisting time related records such as records per month). Do you think it will be alright to leave certain foreign key columns (such as productkey) as N/A in the fact table (as there is no corresponding product rather a brand)?

Comment: If the fact is a discount independent of the product (i.e. at the brand level) then I think it would be fine to have N/A for product.  You will want to have some other way of tying the discount to the specific sale so you focus on product questions.  Your raw fact table can easily answer where the discount came from, but you also need to be able to answer the question "how much have we discounted product X (for any reason)?"  That's why it would be important to link the discount to the sale using a PK/FK relationship.  The original sale will always have a product regardless of any discounts.

Comment: Thanks @Joel, understood. I may need to do some design changes.